# How to get array of pixels from browser window without using canvas

Tags: dom, pixel

I'm attempting to get an array of pixels of the screen (web page) but i know of no way of doing that without using canvas (either straight-up or converting HTML dom elements into canvas, first).  I need to capture every pixel on the screen and i don't know what operating system is going to be used so i can't request the display from the O/S, either.  Is there a third-party tool, possibly, or a way to do this from the window object in the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

I have only one idea. Maybe you should try to move this functionality to the server. You can use WkHtmlToPDF(http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) for saving websites as PDF, pdf file you can convert to an image and read pixels array.

Answer (score 2):

As web developers with no control of the client machine, there's two approaches to getting a screenshot of a webpage:

1. Open the webpage in a headless browser on the server and make the screenshot there. [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)  is a popular one.
2. (I'm including this for completeness, though you said you don't want to take that route): Use the canvas element on the client. [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) is an interesting project that re-renders an entire HTML document into a canvas element so a screenshot can be made.

If your use case allows it, you could of course instruct your users to take a screenshot and paste it in an upload form that can handle images from the clipboard. On Windows, that's a matter of hitting "Print Screen" and CTRL+V.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an api to generate images from online web pages: http://www.page2images.com/Create-Website-Screenshot-with-Javascript-API